# How to remove space between prefixIcon and texformfield text?

Tags: flutter, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

[image]

How to remove space after prefix icon in TextFormField in flutter? I've already tried isCollapsed = true, isDense = true. And I have set my contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0). Using prefix instead of prefixIcon however solves my issue, but there is another problem. Prefix appears only on focus. How to solve my problem? I want to prefix(or prefixIcon) to appear always visible at the beginning. And TextFormField's text must be like continue of the prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Text("118"),
            prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 40)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue with contentPadding i have provided
make it condtional content padding.

```
contentPadding:Padding.only(left:prefixWidget!=null?0:20,),
```